# Persian RadDateTimePicker in C# winform?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, datetimepicker, persian

I like to use `DateTimePicker` in my winforms C# project but both `C#` and `Telerik` Control have Gregorian date.
Can anyone convert these control to Persian `DateTimePicker`?
Is any way for my problem. 
Please help me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is any way in `C#` to set DataTimePicker to Persian. And `Telerik` also do not support such thing take a look [here](http://www.telerik.com/forums/problem-to-change-culture-to-persian).

So I would suggest you to explore other options such as

- [Code project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/selection/FarsiLibrary.aspx?fid=287863&df=90&mpp=25&noise=3&sort=Position&view=Quick&fr=176)
- [Code Plex](http://persiancontrol.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

use the `telerik radDateTimePicker` and write this code , after `InitializeComponent()`, and Instead of "fa-IR" use your culture . enjoy :)

```
Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR"); 
radDateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom; 
radDateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```