# Persian datetimepicker in C# .net windows form

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker, jalali-calendar

I want to get datetime from user in windows form C#.net .I use datetimepicker of .net control but it is gregorian so how can I change This datetimepicker to shamsi date???
[image: DatetimePicker image in winform]

Comment: Have a look at this [PersianDateTimePicker, PersianMonthCalendar](http://persiancontrol.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797234/persian-raddatetimepicker-in-c-sharp-winform)

Comment: There is an open source library created by [@Hadi Eskandari](http://stackoverflow.com/users/54538/hadi-eskandari). Here is the link for [codeproject article](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/), [page of the library](http://seesharpsoftware.com.au/farsilibrary-v2.6-now-available/) in his site and the [nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Farsi.Library/). The library is called FarsiLibrary but its DateTimePicker and MonthView supports Jalali (Shamsi / Persian), Hijri (Qamari / Islamic) and Gregorian.

Answer (score 1):

Previously I tried Behrooz Moghaddam's code but using the default winforms DateTimePicker control, but that code didn't work.

Now I am using the telerik `RadDateTimePicker` and write this code after `InitializeComponent()` and instead of `"fa-IR"` use your culture.

```
Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
radDateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
radDateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```

Answer (score -1):

No need for an additional library. You can change the calander type in Region Setting on the control panel.
And add these lines after `InitializeComponent();`

```
Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("fa-IR");
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = Application.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern;
```